# Electronic tunneling between two states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution, biophysics, quantum-tunneling

I am reading [Steering Electrons on Moving Pathways](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ar900123t) (Beratan et al. 2009) which is  about electron tunneling in biomolecules, and specifically the processes via which an electron can move from an initial state $|D\rangle$ (on the donor side) to a final state $|A\rangle$ (on the acceptor side). In my research, I just came across the following equation:

> The time-dependent transition amplitude from an initial complex (momentum-carrying) state $D$ to a real final state $A$ in a system with Hamiltonian $H$ is given by$$\langle A|e^{-iHt/\hbar}|D\rangle=\sum_m\langle A|\Psi_m\rangle\langle\Psi_m|D\rangle e^{-iE_mt/\hbar}.$$

Here, $\Psi_m$ and $E_m$ are the corresponding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. The reason this confuses me is that I am used to think of transition probabilities as being proportional to $\langle A|H|D\rangle$, per the Schrödinger equation. I had always thought that the time evolution operator $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ introduces a harmless phase factor which does not in and of itself determine quantum dynamics.

So what am I not understanding here? Is this a matter of terminology, or is there a deeper meaning to the time evolution operator in this context that I had not previously been aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system is in the state $|\psi(0)\rangle$ at time $t=0$, it will be in the state $|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi(0)\rangle$ at time $t$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. With $|\psi(0) \rangle = | D \rangle$, $\langle A | e^{-iHt/\hbar} |D \rangle$ is thus the transition amplitude to find the system in the state $|A\rangle$ at time $t$ if it had been in the state $|D\rangle$ at $t=0$. The corresponding transition probability is then given by $|\langle A | e^{-iHt/\hbar} |D \rangle|^2$, being time dependent, in general.

Only in the special case $|D\rangle=|\psi_n\rangle$, where $|\psi_n \rangle$  is (a normalized) eigenvector of the Hamiltonian ($H |\psi_n\rangle = E_n | \psi_n\rangle$), the transition amplitude is just given by $\langle A | e^{-iHt/\hbar} |\psi_n\rangle=\langle A | \psi_n \rangle e^{-iE_n t /\hbar}$ resulting in a time independent transition probability, a rather boring case.

The matrix element $\langle A | H | D \rangle$ (in general a complex number) is certainly NOT a transition probability!

Comment: The expression $\langle A | i H t | D \rangle$ is the first order correction to the transition probability amplitude for short times. For orthogonal $\vert A\rangle, ~\vert D\rangle$ it is the dominant term.